# Proving that the spectrum of a ring generates a topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the spectrum topology. In this topology, for any ideal $I\subset R$ (where $R$ is a commutative ring), a closed set $\Bbb{V}(I)$ is defined to be all prime ideals contained in $I$.

I am trying to prove that the union of two closed sets is also closed. Let $\Bbb{V}(I)$ and $\Bbb{V}(J)$ be two closed sets. What is the ideal $X$ such that $\Bbb{V}(X)=\Bbb{V}(I)\cup\Bbb{V}(J)$?

I thought the ideal would be $I+J$. However, it $\Bbb{V}(I+J)$ might also contain other prime ideals that are not in $\Bbb{V}(I)$ or $\Bbb{V}(J)$

EDIT: I read the definition wrong. As pointed out in the comments, $\Bbb{V}(I)$ is defined to be the set of all prime ideals that **contain** $I$.

Comment: I think $\Bbb{V}(I)$ is defined to be the set of all prime ideals containing $I?$ For example, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring#Zariski_topology).

Comment: @awllower- You're absolutely right. I misread

Comment: NP. Also, the inclusion direction between prime ideals and that between closed sets is reversed, as $A\mapsto \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a contra variant functor. From this it is easy to guess that $X$ should be the intersection, instead of $I+J.$ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $$\Bbb{V}(I\cap J)=\Bbb{V}(I)\cup\Bbb{V}(J).$$
To show this, it is clear that if $I\subseteq\mathfrak p$ or $J\subseteq\mathfrak p,$ then $I\cap J\subseteq\mathfrak p.$
Conversely, if $I\cap J\subseteq\mathfrak p,$ and if $I\nsubseteq p,$ take $x\in I\setminus \mathfrak p,$ then $\forall y\in J,$ we must have $xy\in I\cap J\subseteq\mathfrak p,$ so $y\in\mathfrak p,\forall y\in J,$ i.e. $J\subseteq\mathfrak p.$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ satisfies the following property:

> if $I$ and $J$ are ideals and $IJ\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$, then either $I\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$ or $J\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$

which generalizes the definition (if $ab\in\mathfrak{p}$ then either $a\in\mathfrak{p}$ or $b\in\mathfrak{p}$).

Since $IJ\subseteq I$ and $IJ\subseteq J$, you have
$$
\mathbb{V}(I)\cup\mathbb{V}(J)=\mathbb{V}(IJ)
$$

---

Note that
$$
\mathbb{V}(I)=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}(R):
\mathfrak{p}\supseteq I\}
$$
(and not $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq I$).